# Confusion when it comes to Inheritance Scope

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Here's my code:

```
class Base{
    public:
    getValue(int a){
        x = a;
    }
    protected:
        int x;
    };

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    Derived():Base(){
        Value = 0;
    }
    void Function();
}
```

So my confusion comes from the inheritance when you have to set the scope of the `Base` function in the derived function, in google it says that everything in the base class becomes public. If that is the case, doesn't the protected value in the `Base` function become easily accessible in the `Derived` function? isn't that bad?

If this is the case isn't there a way keep the protected value from the base class protected in the derived class.

Comment: *"..in google it says that everything in the base class becomes public.. "* - Its wrong. Don't always trust Google, there are so many wrong stuff on C++ out there. See [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance?rq=1).

Comment: BTW, its not called *"scope"*, *"scope"* is about something else. Your subject is themed on [*"member access specification"*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)

Answer (score 3):

Public inheritance does not mean that everything becomes public. It means that what is public from `Base` becomes public in `Derived`. The protected data member, is not made public.

If you had used protected inheritance, then the public methods of `Base` would be made protected in `Derived`. Had you used private inheritance, then the public and protected methods in `Base` would be private in `Derived`.

I guess you can say that the inheritance encapsulation instructs the maximum visibility of the base class, not the absolute visibility of it.

Edit: Actually the link provided by WhiZTiM explains it quite nicely: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)